# UIwebview touch and get element and show border

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I have UIwebview in my iphone app.

I would like to highlight Element (Paragrah) when user touch in uiwebView.

I am using some java code to help me get element but it is not working. I am not java expert so need some help from expert please.

Code:

```
NSString *selectedElement = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection()"];
NSLog (@"selectedElement : %@",selectedElement);
```

Output is always :

```
selectedElement  : <BODY>
```

My final goal is touch anywhere in UIwebview and element should be highlight with border or light background color.

e.g in following image paragraph is highlight when user touch any where on that paragraph {between : The Apple....you buy a Mac.} However I do not want to have event occur on Long press nor highglight single word.

[image]

Hope someone get give me somehint.

Comment: I'm also facing same problem as you faced early. Can you pls guide me..

Answer (score 1):

Few month ago I have done the same task. For javascript side I used [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) - wonderful library that help a lot with selection in web page. 
After initing library all you need is apply custom css style to selection

After all `.js` loaded into webview you need to call `[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"rangy.init()"];`

To make change background of selected content you need css style I created one with this code:

```
NSString * selectionCSS =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@".uiwebViewSelected%@ { background-color: %@ }", @"redColor", @"#FF0000"];

NSString * customCssJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" var style = document.createElement('style'); \
                          style.type = 'text/css'; \
                          style.innerHTML = '%@'; \
                          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);", selectionCSS];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: customCssJS];
```

Then for last step - create cssApplier object with

```
NSString * cssApplier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cssApplier%@ = rangy.createCssClassApplier('uiwebViewSelected%@', {normalize: true});",  @"redColor", @"redColor"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:cssApplier];
```

All necessary initialization is completed. To apply css to selection call `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"cssApplierRedColor.toggleSelection(window.getSelection()[0]);"]`

Comment: Thanks sage444 I am new to JAVA so don't know how to use these in iOS !! Can you please guide me where to start?

Comment: the rangy, as I remember, have good examples, You need just play with it in uiwebview and all will become clean.

Comment: Thanks sage444 I still not getting it. Is it possible for you guide me with sample code?

Comment: sorry I cant provide code because is heavy integrated into my project. In short a do this steps: 1 - add rangy to my bundle as resources. 2 - in UIwebview delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` load libs with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:rangySource]`; and all `rangy.Init` with same method - is necessary minimum

Comment: Thanks This is what I did!!       NSString *txtFilePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rangy-selectionsaverestore" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *txtFileContents2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    
   [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:txtFileContents2];
 What to do next?

Comment: I added code to answer, but this is just cuts from project, you need a polish it before use.